# Format input type text with date format when the value is filled by a button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to format a input type text with forward slashes (/) to make it look like a date in this format = "DD/MM/YYY"

The only issue is, the values that i insert into the input are not coming from my keyboard, i mean, i'm not typing them, instead, i have a DIV with a digital keyboard on the screen.

Inside that div, i have multiple buttons with different values but the same classes applied to all of them (".buttonsDigitalKeyboard") , and at the click of each button inside that div, the value from the button clicked goes to my input.

I did make this formatting work when i type the value directly from my keyboard, but that can't be allowed on the project, the user has to use the digital keyboard that is being shown on the screen and i can't figure out a way to apply this when the buttons are clicked.

Does anyone have any ideia how i can make this work?

Appreciate all the help

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    const input_value = $("#inputText"); 
    $(".buttonsDigitalKeyboard").click(function () { 
        let value = $(this).val();  //
        field(value); 
    });

    function field(value) {
        input_value.val(input_value.val() + value); 
    }

});
```

```html
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="inputText">
<div class="col mt-2">
  <button class="buttonsDigitalKeyboard" value="0"> 0 </button>
  <button class="buttonsDigitalKeyboard" value="1"> 1 </button>
  <button class="buttonsDigitalKeyboard" value="2"> 2 </button>
  <button class="buttonsDigitalKeyboard" value="3"> 3 </button>
  <button class="buttonsDigitalKeyboard" value="4"> 4 </button>
  <button class="buttonsDigitalKeyboard" value="5"> 5 </button>
  <button class="buttonsDigitalKeyboard" value="6"> 6 </button>
  <button class="buttonsDigitalKeyboard" value="7"> 7 </button>
  <button class="buttonsDigitalKeyboard" value="8"> 8 </button>
  <button class="buttonsDigitalKeyboard" value="9"> 9 </button>
  <button class="buttonsDigitalKeyboard" value="10"> 10 </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't make much sense of this, this lacks too much context. Like, we don't even know what the values of those buttons actually _are_. You should provide a proper [mre] when you ask a question like this.

Comment: I just edited my question and provided an example of the actual scenario

Comment: Okay, so you are appending digits to the value, one by one. In that case, it should be enough if you check how long the current field value is - if the current length is 2 or 5, then you want to append a `/` first, before you append the current digit. (This is under the assumption that you don't have any functionality to remove digits again - but from the given example, I can't see anything like that.)